# IntelliJ 2022.2 crashes on on MacOS opening project via "recently opened"

Tags: intellij-idea, crash, ide

Since upgrading to Intellij IDEA 2022.2 the IDE crashes frequently, when I open a project via "File | Open Recent".

After that the IDE crashes on startup.

To solve the immediate problem, I can open /Users//Library/Application\ Support/IntelliJIdea2018.2/optionsJetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/options/recentProjects.xml and delete opened="true" from the -Tag of the project causing the problem. But this only fixes it temporarily.

Apple Crash Report

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               idea [23792]
Path:                  /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.intellij
Version:               2022.2.3 (IU-222.4345.14)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
...
Date/Time:             2022-11-08 08:36:23.9671 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.6.1 (21G217)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     7.0 (20P411)
...

Time Awake Since Boot: 69000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       762 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        40  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4367908864
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      104590000-104598000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ts/MacOS/idea

Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
```

Comment: Please provide a complete report of the crash, not only the header. It is necessary to check the stacktrace of the thread `Java: Java2D Queue Flusher`. Check if upgrading to build 2022.3 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion helps.

Comment: same on PHPStorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by changes in intellij and it was solved by an update of the software.